# Javascript fill html input form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a generated list of Buttons:

```
<?php 
    echo "<td> <button id=\"{$cell}\" onclick=\"ausfüllen($cell)\">{$cell}</button></td>" 
?>
```

and I want to call a JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    function ausfüllen(text) {
         document.getElementById("nv_durchwahl").value = "dw";
    }
</script>
```

to fill out some other `<td>`:

```
<td> 
    <input type="text" id="nv_durchwahl" name="nv_durchwahl" value="">
</td>
```

This is how i tried it.

The buttons are generated without any problem but it doesn't fill out the form.

Any ideas where I went off in this one?

Comment: Unless i am mistaken you are not calling your script anywhere ?

Comment: please closing brace is missing in your javascript function

Comment: Actually i should be, in the first code snippit there should be the ausführen() called. and  on click it should be done then.

I have the closing brace in it but it was just one line of the script.

Or am i wrong?
Its the first try i ever had with javascript.

Comment: The field with id `nv_durchwahl` is unique? Because if you have more with the same id, wouldn't work. Besides, try to see the console log on Developer Tools (F12) to see if there's any error thrown.

Comment: Thanks Dimas the tip with the Developer console was helpful.
On top of that my Value that i wanted to set was once called dw, renamed it to text and didnt rename the variable to it. 

Fixed it.
function ausfüllen(text) {
    document.getElementById("nv_durchwahl").value = text;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the function bracket

```
<script>
    function ausfüllen(text) {
        document.getElementById("nv_durchwahl").value = "dw";
    }
</script>
```

And there is no element with ID "nv_durchwahl".

Comment: There is, and i just missed that in my copying.

I got everything of that.

Comment: If $cell is a string you have to use single quotation marks: <?php echo "<td> <button id=\"{$cell}\" 
onclick=\"ausfüllen('$cell')\">{$cell}</button></td>" ?>

Answer (score 0):

try to concatenate this way... the function ausfüllen receives a string, check how is being translated into html code...

```
<?php 
    echo "<td> <button id='".{$cell}."' onclick='ausfüllen(".'"'.{$cell}.'"'.")'>".{$cell}."</button></td>"; 
?>
```

when you say

> fill out the form.

means putting on the element with id "nv_durchwahl" (which should be unique) the value "dw" or the content of "text" variable?

```
<script>
    function ausfüllen(text) {
         //set the value of the element with the specific id to "dw"
         //text is never used!
         document.getElementById("nv_durchwahl").value = "dw";
    }
</script>
```